# Does the trivial measure provide a counterexample to the following statement about the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

On the Wikipedia page for non-measurable sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set), the following statement appears:

"The Banach–Tarski paradox shows that there is no way to define volume in three dimensions unless one of the following four concessions is made:

- The volume of a set might change when it is rotated.
- The volume of the union of two disjoint sets might be different from the sum of their volumes.
- Some sets might be tagged "non-measurable", and one would need to check whether a set is "measurable" before talking about its volume.
- The axioms of ZFC (Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory with the axiom of choice) might have to be altered."

By "define volume in three dimensions", I'm assuming they mean "define a measure on $\mathbb R^3$". However, it would seem to me that the trivial measure where every set is assigned a measure of zero would not need any of these concessions. Have I misunderstood something or did the author simply type "no way to define volume" when they meant to say "no way to define non-trivial volume"? Or is there some other criterion that is implicit in the notion of "volume in three dimensions" that the trivial measure (possibly along with others) does not meet?

Comment: To me, especially since that is an informal paragraph, “volume” connotes “size” which disagrees with the trivial measure

Comment: I would take it to mean that the volume to be defined agrees with ordinary volume of 3-dimensional geometry on the sets defined in geometry.  In particular, a cube with side $1$ has volume $1$.  Perhaps the Wikipedia page should be altered?

Comment: @GEdgar thanks! If I understand correctly you seem to imply that there might be a (non-trivial) measure which disagrees with conventional geometry which is 'impervious' to the Banach-Tarski paradox, is that so?

Comment: @GEdgar Perhaps, but the way I read it gives a much stronger statement: Any non-trivisl function $V:\mathcal P(\Bbb R^3)\to[0,\infty]$ must have at least one of the problems listed...

Comment: Yes, of course the zero measure is a counterexample - the author needs to say "non-trivial". But imo no, "volume" here does not necessarily refer to a measure! It seems to me he's saying that if $V:\mathcal P(\Bbb R^3)\to[0,\infty]$ and $V$ is not identically zero then one of those pathologies must happen

Comment: One should explicitly ask for translation as well as rotation invariance. Otherwise, a reader might only consider rotations fixing the origin which allows point mass at the origin as a counterexample. With that adjustment, I think one is closer to a true statement, but there are at least a few more trivial examples to exclude apart from the identically zero measure. For example, $V(S)=\begin{cases}\infty & \text{if $S$ is nonempty} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ or, slightly more interesting, $V(S)=\begin{cases}\infty & \text{if $S$ is unbounded} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If volume means measure, then to be correct there would need to be a fifth statement, something like "The volume of $[0,1]^3$ is $0$ or $\infty$". Else, as you said, the trivial measure would be an example (and the measure assigning measure $\infty$ to every set but the empty set would be another). As is, the paragraph is not formally correct but not really formal anyways.